# Should rear wheel be trued without cassette?

Tags: wheel-truing

Should rear wheel be trued with or without a cassette installed?
If I attempt to true it without a cassette, does not it mean that once we install the cassette, it will exert some force on the rim and move it effectively towards one side, making the wheel untrue, or is it very negligible?
Thank you

Comment: The spoke tension in the order of magnitude of 100kgF, so the weight of the cassette is negligible in comparison (especially considering that the load is distributed around many spokes).

Comment: Even more importantly, the cassette doesn't even touch the spokes, rim or hub shell.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a question.  Is there some edge case where a cassette could somehow effect the wheel trueness??  Genuinely baffled by why anyone would ask this

Comment: "the cassette, it will exert some force on the rim[...]?" how?

Comment: Aside - you should generally build and true a wheel without a rimtape or tyre installed.  The tyre and tape will affect things, so for any more than a quick tweak, off with the rubber.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rear wheel can be trued both with or without the cassette installed.
When building a new wheel, the cassette will always be removed. Otherwise, you could not get the spokes into the hub.

The Cassette will not exert any force on the rim.